# Open CSV data in tableau

Tags: r, tableau-desktop

I have had problems uploading the following file to Tableau:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows/download

[image]

When loaded it looks like this

but loading it in R

[image]

Is it possible to load them in R and then by Rserve connect to tableau or is there a way to load them fine

Comment: The problem is that the "csv" file has fields that are wrapped in quotation marks.  Inside these there are extra commas.  You could use R to save tsv or use some other delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem within the interpreter.

I can't download the file myself as I don't have a Kaggle account, and its not clear from you R screenshots, though you could adjust the text file properties to see if you can adjust how the interpreter works by right-mouse the object "netflix_titles.csv" in the data model window and selecting *Text file properties* from the context menu.

Another option would be to try to use the interpreter *Usar el intérprete de datos*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tableau is reading this file as a Text file and not a CSV.  Tableau should have multiple headers for every comma that it sees but your screenshot has a single column for the entire first row.

Sometimes, Tableau can correctly read the file if you check the "Use Data Interpreter" checkbox.

If you have trouble making that work, just simply open the CSV in Excel and save it as an XLSX.  You could even connect to it via an import to Google Sheets if you don't have Excel.